# What is dynamic (importlib) equivalent of "from module import *"?

Tags: python, python-import

How to override current module by importing another module using `importlib`?

From example:

```py
foo = 'bar'
# ...

from module import *

imported_baz.spam = 'fds'
```

But I want to use `importlib` instead of `from module import *`. Do I need to update `locals()` dict somehow?

Comment: `from foo import *` is normally considered bad style, can you give a bit more context on what your use case is?

Comment: @Chris_Rands importing just basic django settings after loading dotenv file

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @SpaceKatt because my problem is not really a problem, i like my django settings configuration flow. The only problem is rogue import which by convention should be at the top of the file.

Comment: If you're using dotenv, then I would recommend using the standard way of loading config in using dotenv https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/